# GeoTools and PostGIS coordinate transformation gets different result

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, geotools, rgdal, jts-topology-suite

I've got a problem transforming coordinates. The result differs in PostGIS and GeoTools.

I want to transform from EPSG:4326 to EPSG:3398.

PostGIS:

```
indicia=> select ST_AsText(ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(13.387527 54.094434)', 4326),3398)) as converted;
                converted                 
------------------------------------------
 POINT(4590768.20978302 5996697.68142438)
(1 row)
```

```
CoordinateReferenceSystem sourceCRS = CRS.decode("EPSG:4326");
CoordinateReferenceSystem targetCRS = CRS.decode("EPSG:3398");
WKTReader wktReader = new WKTReader(new GeometryFactory(new PrecisionModel()));
WKTWriter wktWriter = new WKTWriter();
MathTransform mathTransform = CRS.findMathTransform(sourceCRS, targetCRS, true);
Geometry geom = wktReader.read("POINT(54.094434 13.387527)");
Geometry transformed = JTS.transform(geom, mathTransform);
System.out.println(wktWriter.write(transformed));
```

Returns: `POINT (5996634.451525969 4590769.450296965)`

This means the GeoTools result is about 60m south of the PostGIS result.

`rgdal` for R is giving the same result as PostGIS.

Am I doing something wrong in using geotools/jts?

Comment: what happens if you don't set lenient true in findTransform?

Comment: and which epgs database are you using?

Comment: lenient `false` results into an exception: `org.opengis.referencing.operation.OperationNotFoundException: Bursa wolf parameters required.`

Comment: The epsg database is `gt-epsg-hsql` 19.1 but also upgrading to 20.3 did not change the result

Comment: Probably means PostGIS is using the Bursa Wolf params and GeoTools doesn't know about them

Comment: Is there a way to extract the Bursa Wolf params from PostGIS and add them to GeoTools?

Comment: http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/faq.html#q-bursa-wolf-parameters-required